# Windows Phone 8.1 Media Elements

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have currently 2 buttons, Audi TT RS and Audi R8
when the user clicks on button TT RS it plays a mp3, when user clicks on button R8 it opens a different mp3 file.

This works, however... if the user clicks on one of them, and then clicks on the other. both mp3 files will open and it will sound terrible.

those are my functions :

```
async void Audir8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
            if (mediaplayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                mediaplayer.Stop();
            }
            // get folder app is installed to
            var installFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            // get folders mp3 files are installed to.
            var resourcesFolder = await installFolder.GetFolderAsync("Resources");
            var mp3FilesFolder = await resourcesFolder.GetFolderAsync("mp3Files");
            // open the mp3 file async
            var audioFile = await mp3FilesFolder.GetFileAsync("audir8.mp3");
            // var stream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            using (var stream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                // play dat funky music
             //   MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
                mediaplayer.SetSource(stream, audioFile.ContentType);

                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                mediaplayer.CurrentStateChanged += (_, __) =>
                {
                    if (mediaplayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Opening &&
                        mediaplayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing &&
                        mediaplayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Buffering)
                    // mediaplayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.AcquiringLicense)
                    {
                        // Any other state should mean we're done playing
                        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
                    }
                };
                mediaplayer.Play();
                await tcs.Task; // Asynchronously wait for media to finish
            }
        }
```

and the other one, actually the same..

```
 async void Audittrs_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
            if (mediaplayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                mediaplayer.Stop();
            }
            // get folder app is installed to
            var installFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
            // get folders mp3 files are installed to.
            var resourcesFolder = await installFolder.GetFolderAsync("Resources");
            var mp3FilesFolder = await resourcesFolder.GetFolderAsync("mp3Files");
            // open the mp3 file async
            var audioFile = await mp3FilesFolder.GetFileAsync("ttrs.mp3");
            // var stream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            using (var stream = await audioFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                // play dat funky music
              //  MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
                mediaplayer.SetSource(stream, audioFile.ContentType);

                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                mediaplayer.CurrentStateChanged += (_, __) =>
                {
                    if (mediaplayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Opening &&
                        mediaplayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing &&
                        mediaplayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Buffering)
                    // mediaplayer.CurrentState != MediaElementState.AcquiringLicense)
                    {
                        // Any other state should mean we're done playing
                        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
                    }
                };
                mediaplayer.Play();
                await tcs.Task; // Asynchronously wait for media to finish
            }
        }
```

I thought this should not happen since I am using

```
MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
            if (mediaplayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing)
            {
                mediaplayer.Stop();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set up your mediaplayer local variable, you're creating a new mediaplayer, not re-using the one you've previously created.  If you re-use the previously-created one (say by making it a field plus property in your class), then the `.Stop()` call should stop the previous sound.

If you do this, you'll have to change the first line of each of your `..._Click` methods to use the persistent MediaElement.

For example, in your class you can do something like this:

```
private MediaElement _mediaplayer;

public MediaElement Mediaplayer
{
  get{
    if( _mediaplayer == null )
    {
      _mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
    }
    return _mediaplayer;
  }
}
```

Then in your `..._Click` methods, swap out this:

```
MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
```

... for this:

```
MediaElement mediaplayer = this.Mediaplayer;
```

The getter should do the rest, making sure that you're always using the same MediaElement for the various sounds you play, allowing you to stop previously-playing sounds as you desire.

Comment: Error 1 'HDCAR.MainPage' does not contain a definition for 'Mediaplayer' and no extension method 'Mediaplayer' accepting a first argument of type 'HDCAR.MainPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Halt\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\HDCAR\HDCAR\MainPage.xaml.cs 118 45 HDCAR

Comment: Sounds like you didn't put the public MediaElement Mediaplayer... code in your class.